# Drupal SQL errors when opening on Localhost Xampp

Tags: mysql, drupal, server, xampp, localhost

Good day all, i get this error when bringing my project fro a live server to localhost in xampp. Drupal project. Please kindly assist. Thanks.

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 
1146 Table 'plaindrupal.semaphore' doesn't exist: 
SELECT expire, value FROM {semaphore} WHERE
name = :name; Array ( [:name] => variable_init ) in 
lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of C:\xampp\htdocs\plain\includes\lock.inc).
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :) It would be helpful if you could provide the code that is causing this error and additional information that would help us figure out exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Aadekunle-henry, That probably means that you have config in settings php to the empty db, please check to which db you have connected in your setting.php and put live db backup there, or just for fast check - try to remove sites/default/settings.php file and open your local site again - you should see installation page.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the database of the live server has not been dumped in your local database server correctly.The issue is due to the unavailability of semaphore table in your  local database.Backup your live database server and dump it in your local database server. It will solve your issue.